# Retrieving UserAuth data from Firebase in an Ionic project

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm struggling to retrieve UserAuth data from firebase and presenting it on a list. I managed to put it there, but I can't get it back. I'v been around so many diffrent tutorials and tested a lot of code :(

Are there any suggestions to this issue? My code looks like this. It's probably totally wrong.

html:

```
<div *ngIf="userAppointment">
 <ion-card *ngFor="let appointment of userAppointment | async">
  <!-- <img [src]="appointment.brand.brandimage" alt="BrandImage"> -->
  <ion-card-content text-wrap>
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-left>
            <h2>{{appointment.products}}</h2>
            <p>{{appointment.price}}</p>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col text-right>
            <h2>{{appointment.date}}</h2>
            <p>{{appointment.time}}</p>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
  </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-  angular';
import { DataService } from '../../providers/data/data.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth/auth.service';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { Appointment } from '../../models/appointments/appointments';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-list',
  templateUrl: 'appointment-list.component.html'
})

export class AppointmentListComponent implements OnInit {

userAppointment: Appointment;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
  this.data.getAppointment(user).subscribe((appointment: Appointment)  => {
    this.userAppointment = appointment;
  });
 });
}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,   private data: DataService, private auth: AuthService) {
 }
}
```

Provider/DataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { Appointment } from '../../models/appointments/appointments';
import "rxjs/add/operator/take";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  appointmentlist: FirebaseListObservable<Appointment[]> 

constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
}

getAppointment(user: User) {
  this.appointmentlist = this.database.list(`/appointments/${user.uid}`, {preserveSnapshot: true });
  return this.appointmentlist.take(1);
  }

}
```

The data structure on FireBase looks like this:
[DataStructure on Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0999.png)

I hope there is someone out there who can point me in the right direction.

Best regards
Peter